# Text overflow in agenda views

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am not quite sure what the best way to describe what I'm looking for is, so let me start with a picture. This is the result of doing a search for all `TODO` items in my `agenda-files` with a certain tag.

[image]

Whenever a `TODO` item is too long, the overflow text appears on the following line, as one would expect. But rather than being indented with the rest of the `TODO` items, it is aligned fully to the left of the window. Is there away around this? Either showing only what fits on the column containing all `TODO`  (and just cutting off the rest) or indenting accordingly would do.

Comment: What happens if you type `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`?  I thought that truncating lines was the default in the agenda buffer, but then again I am using an outdated version of `org-mode`.  If `toggle-truncate-lines` achieves the desired visual effect, then you can programmatically set line-truncation for org agenda buffers ....

Comment: Toggle-truncate-lines sort of works. The problem is that tags are no longer visible. (And I guess the default is to have it disabled now... at least with whichever version of `org-mode` I'm working with.)

Comment: So, it sounds like you want what appears to be a custom solution; i.e., you would like the line truncated, but you would still like to see the tags ...  I do not believe that `org-mode` does this out of the box and would likely require a custom modification.  Although I am the only person I can think of who would do this, it is possible to modify the data as it is being collected and only insert the modified result into the org agenda buffer.  Other people would probably modify the buffer after the fact using something like the `org-agenda-finalize-hook`; or, just live with it ....

Comment: Yeah, might just learn to live with it.